# Using a query for SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I have a parameterized query, for demo purpose let's assume it's

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM People 
WHERE Age >= @Age
```

Let's assume this could be millions of records and I want to bulk load those records into a table `Population (Id, Name)`.

By following most examples I see of `SqlBulkCopy` I would use the first query to get a datatable and then I can Bulk load that datatable into `Population` but there is no need for me to read the query, put it into memory just to write it again. Essentially I want to have my query bulk loaded into the table without ever having to read the query in C#, all the IO should happen in the database.

How do I go about this? Here is my attempt:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Name FROM People WHERE Age >= @Age";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", 10);

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SomeConnectionString))
    {
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[Population]";
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        bulkcopy.Close();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if `ExecuteReader` just sets a pointer to start reading or actually reads the query into memory.

Before someone recommends executing the query

```
INSERT INTO Population
    SELECT Id, Name 
    FROM People 
    WHERE Age >= @Age
```

Know that the query I want to bulk load would come in as a variable (with parameters) as I don't know what the query will be, just that I expect it to map well and I want it bulk loaded.

Comment: What was the result of your attempt?  ExecuteReader() does not load the query results into memory.  You have to iterate of the resultant reader.

Comment: The main example for `SQlBulkCopy` on MSDN is doing this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_WriteToServer_System_Data_IDataReader_

Comment: I get `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.` and enabling MARS is not an option

Comment: Without MARS, there is no other way than using `DataTable` and use it for `SqlBulkCopy`, since you cannot use same connection for bulk copy while the data reader is still open. You must close first connection to use with `SqlBulkCopy` later.

Comment: The comments more or less answered this sufficiently. Someone feel free to create an answer for acceptance, otherwise I'll close (I dont want to close because I feel its useful information someone else can google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Comments:

Without MARS, there is no other way than using DataTable and use it for SqlBulkCopy, since you cannot use same connection for bulk copy while the data reader is still open. You must close first connection to use with SqlBulkCopy later.